# Accessing dynamically defined class as constant works only with const_get

Tags: ruby

Given the following example:

```
[1] pry(main)>
[2] pry(main)> module Foo
[2] pry(main)*   Foo = 'LOL'
[2] pry(main)*   ['Lol'].each do |elem|
[2] pry(main)*     @elem = elem
[2] pry(main)*     Object.const_set "Bar#{elem}", Class.new { def butts; puts "#{@elem}" end;  }
[2] pry(main)*   end
[2] pry(main)* end
=> ["Lol"]
[3] pry(main)> Foo.constants
=> [:Foo]
[4] pry(main)> Foo.const_get('BarLol')
=> BarLol
[5] pry(main)> Foo::Foo
=> "LOL"
[6] pry(main)> Foo::BarLol
NameError: uninitialized constant Foo::BarLol
from (pry):11:in `<main>'
[7] pry(main)>
```

1. Why is it when I do `Foo.constants` it returns one constant. Shouldn't it be returning `[:Foo, :BarLol]`?
2. Also why is it that the only way you can access the value of the dynamically defined constant is to do `Foo.const_get('BarLol')`?  Why doesn't `Foo::BarLol` not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue is that you're setting `BarLol` constant in `Object`'s scope instead of `Foo`'s scope, a small change will work:

```
module Foo
  Foo = 'LOL'
  ['Lol'].each do |elem|
    @elem = elem
    ::Foo.const_set "Bar#{elem}", Class.new { def butts; puts "#{@elem}" end;  }
  end
end

p Foo.constants
#=> [:Foo, :BarLol]
p Foo.const_get('BarLol')
#=> Foo::BarLol
p Foo::Foo
#=> "LOL"
p Foo::BarLol
#=> Foo::BarLol
```